# cannot call httprequest with curl internally in php

Tags: php, linux, http, curl

I setup a symfony project to play on, then create two routes in a controller. Inside the route 1, making a call with curl to route 2. Look like below:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="user_list")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

    $url = 'http://localhost:8000/test';
    $headers = array( 'Authorization' => 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump( $result );

    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render("user/user_list.html.twig");
}

/**
 * @Route("/test", name="user_test")
 */
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    return new Response('abc', 200);
}
```

If I run router 2 separately,it will return abc, but if I run router 1, it will be waiting connecting always.

How do I solve? Is there anything to configure in php etc, socket...?
Can someone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="user_list")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

    $url = 'http://localhost:8000/test';
    $headers = array( 'Authorization' => 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false) { // Get curl error with this
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }


    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump( $result );

    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render("user/user_list.html.twig");
}
```

Please reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) as above mention

Comment: Code-only answers are only helpful in a copy/paste capacity. It is much better to explain the solution.